# AutoCompleteTextView Listener when popup is showing

Tags: android, popup, listener, autocompletetextview

In my app I'm using a AutoCompleteTextView to select some data. Unfortunately it is possible that the data can change while the AutoCompleteTextView is already on the screen.

Therefore, I want to update the data right before the popup-list is shown.

Is there any lister to execute a function, when the little triagle is clicked?

I already tried:

- setOnFocusChangeListener
- setOnTouchListener
- setOnCreateContextMenuListener

and several more, but nothing really worked.